# asp.net BasePage attribute Code is thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, cookies

My website development base on ASP.NET Webform

All Page inherit `BasePage`

BasePage have a code

[image]

Is the thread of this code safe?

Comment: please share your codes, BasePage and children pages,